# renderInContext unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext

In an iOS app written in Swift I handle graphics, everything seems to work fine until I hit a case with a problem.
The app crashes on this line of code:

```
self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

The message I get in the debugger is:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

In order to understand a bit further, I rewrote the code like this:

```
    if let _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        print("UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext-YES-")
        let x = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.layer.renderInContext(x)
    } else {print("UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext-NO-")}
```

Then I see the message `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext-YES-`, showing that `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` did not return `nil`, but a crash still happens on:
            self.layer.renderInContext(x)

Since `renderInContext` is not a function I wrote, there is not much I can do to see what is going wrong inside.

If anyone has an idea on what I can do, please let me know.

Comment: Is `layer` definitely not `nil`?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but why using `if let _` and then unnecessarily implicitly unwrapping the same again as `x`. Just do: `if let x = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() { }`

Comment: To Eendje: you are totally right. I just wrote that quickly to see what was happening.

Comment: To Rich Tolley: you mean self.layer? I just checked and it is not nil. As a matter of fact, I think if it was nil, it would just do nothing. Am I wrong?

Comment: @michel It would crash if it was another implicitly dereferenced optional and it was `nil` - but now I check [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layer) for `UIView` I see that's impossible (I'm assuming `self` is a `UIView`).

Comment: Yes indeed, in that case you are right. Also yes, self is a `UIView`.
Anyway I solved my problem. By digging further, I realized that the file, where my image was supposed to come from, in fact did not exist. So I presume there was garbage instead of the self.layer, making a crash to happen.

Comment: @Michel did you got solution for this? i am facing same issue.

Comment: @Tejas The solution is written in my last comment. Just the one before you own.